# Peel The Onion of Ciphers

Tags: cipher

What is it that lurks in the center, that is the source of this code?

Z girk rmgl Ilnv hszoo wl.
Qfmt eu tfi Cio.
mfkm qiwfq j fofv, vpgyqaq zsuwn wyb chhxz. fm cnl d mef snj cxdorl, qx qyrd 
cjbfvdwns rzfwbi.

Hint:

> The third line is like the autokey, but different.
>  A nested cipher, the keys are found within.

Hint 2:

> Let the trail guide you, let each key guide you to the next.

Comment: A hint please? :P

Comment: @NL628, If it helps, the first word of the third line is each, and the puzzle relies on decoding the remaining parts with different keys.

Answer (score 10):

### Partial Solution

From the first line, we get

> A trip to Rome shall do. I found this by plugging it into a decoder on quipquip.com

The first line was, in fact, about

> Rome, so plugging the second line into a Caesar Cipher, we get "What is the Key?"

I've tried

> "What" and "Caesar" and "Rome" for the third line, but none of these keys work.

Comment: Everybody knows that [Yog-Sothoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yog-Sothoth) is the Key :P

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer,

First Line,

> When I put this into a backwards decoder I got that the first line says "**A trip into Rome shall do.**"

Second Line,

> Is "**What is the key**" from Matthew King

Third Line,

> ?

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer:

> When run through an Atbash cipher, the first line reads "A trip into Rome shall do."
> This gave me the idea to use a Caesar cipher, so using a rot13 on new code, the second line now reads "What is the Key"
> This is where I got stuck. I've tried using "what" as the key to a Vigenère Cipher, but to no avail.

Comment: If you run the last line through all the ciphers you mentioned, the first word becomes "each". It may be a coincidence, but then again, it may not. I checked the Autoclave (autokey Vigenère) cipher too, since it works identically with Vigenère for the first word, but sadly, to no avail. I also tried to guess the keys so that the single letter words would both turn into I or A, but no success there either.

Comment: tried using portunus as the key as well (roman god of keys...)